# How to sum over half integers?

Tags: summation, integer-sequence

I have an expression of the form

`Sum[1 + x^n + x^(n^2/2), {n, 0, 10}]`

but I want to sum over half integers, that is, I require that $n \in \mathbb{Z}+\frac{1}{2}$ (and later I also want to consider other fractions).

How can I make mathematica, therefore to sum over $\mathbb{Z}+\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: So, `Sum[1 + x^n + x^(n^2/2), {n, Range[0, 10] + 1/2}]`?

Comment: Oh, is it that simple? Ok thanks! Can instead of Range[..] have a set? Like $\matbb{Z}+1/2?$

Answer (score 1):

```
Sum[1 + x^n + x^(n^2/2), {n, 0.5, 10.5}]
```

Comment: Also `Sum[1 + x^n + x^(n^2/2), {n, 1/2, 10 + 1/2}]`